# Copy constructor not deleted on c++ class

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class that never duplicates as it has a LOT of data inside of its fields. To do this I defined the class like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
   Foo(int i);
   Foo();
   Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
}
```

This causes a compiler error if I tried to do something like:

```
Foo a(2);
Foo b = a;
```

However for whatever reason this does not cover this scenario where data is copied.

```
Foo* array;
array = new Foo[10000];
Foo a(2);
array[1] = a;
```

Why is this?

Comment: `Foo a();` is a function declaration.

Comment: `Foo a();` - compiler error resulting from here would have nothing to do with copy constructor - that does not define a `Foo` object, it declares a function.

Comment: In this example, `Foo` has no constructors at all. Declaring a constructor, even to delete it, prevents the default constructor from being generated. You would need to declare the default constructor.

Comment: **−1** Especially the last example is clearly **not real code**. Also voted to close as lacking a reproducible example.

Comment: Updated the question with a constructor and some small edits. Hopefully this is less psuedocodey for y'all.

Comment: What about the `compiler error` you receive?

Comment: @J.Doe, unfortunately, you can't use `array = new Foo[10000];` unless you have a default constructor.

Comment: Gotcha. Updated question again. I didnt feel the need to include more than necessary code for Foo but I can see the confusion it causes so added a default constructor. Believe it or not the class I am writing is not named Foo.

Comment: Time to review the basics of constructors including definition & when they are called.

Answer (score 7):

First of all,

```
Foo a();
```

does not create an object of type `Foo`. It declares a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Foo`.

Assuming that you have an object of type `Foo`,

```
Foo b = a;
```

calls the copy constructor to initialize `b`. However, when you use

```
array[1] = a;
```

it does not use the copy constructor. It is an assignment operation. `delete`ing the copy constructor does not `delete` the copy assignment operator. Hence, the last line is not an error.

Comment: There is still the problem that `Foo` is not default constructible.

Comment: Ah so assignment does not cause any new memory to be used? Simple two locations pointing at the same object?

Comment: @J.Doe, there are two different objects. The value of one object is assgined to the other object.

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: @J.Doe Assignment won't involve the copy constructor, but rather the assignment operator overload.

Comment: That said, one of the simplest ways to implement the assignment operator uses the copy constructor. [See the Copy and Swap Idiom.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) Note that while it is simple and bulletproof, Copy and Swap can be expensive.